# How to build a python dictionary from a list of keys and a list values, quickly?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value, enumerate

I have to lists

```
labels = ['normal.']
percentages = [0.9936]
```

I want to build a dictionary from these two lists

```
d = {}
for k, v in enumerate(lables, percentages):
    d[k] = v
```

But i'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

What could be wrong here ?

**Edit**

Then when i get the dict, i want to perform this operation

```
result = [str(k) + ": " + str(v) for k, v in previous_dict]
```

Comment: That would only happen if you spelled enumerate correctly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the two lists together, and convert the zipped object to a dictionary. After that you can iterate on `dict.items()` to create your list

```
In [158]: labels = ['normal.'] 
     ...: percentages = [0.9936]                                                                                                                                                    

In [159]: previous_dict = dict(zip(labels,percentages))  
In [159]: previous_dict                                                                                                                              
Out[159]: {'normal.': 0.9936}

In [24]: result = [str(k) + ": " + str(v) for k, v in previous_dict.items()]                                                                                                        

In [25]: result                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[25]: ['normal.: 0.9936']
```

Also [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) gives you a list of tuples of type `(index, element)`, you cannot pass it two iterators like that but you can `zip` the two iterators again and make a dictionary, and the code will be as follows.

For Python 3.6+ we can also use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) to format our string as well

```
In [167]: labels = ['normal.'] 
     ...: percentages = [0.9936]                                                                                                                                                    

In [169]: d = {} 
     ...: for k, v in zip(labels, percentages): 
     ...:     d[k] = v 

In [170]: d                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[170]: {'normal.': 0.9936}

In [30]: result = [f'{k}:{v}' for k, v in previous_dict.items()]                                                                                                                    

In [31]: result                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[31]: ['normal.:0.9936']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using list comprehension which you were trying to do. To get the second step working, you need to use `.items()` to access both, the key and the value

```
labels = ['normal.']
percentages = [0.9936]

previous_dict = {k:v for k, v in zip(labels, percentages)}
# {'normal.': 0.9936}

result = [str(k) + ": " + str(v) for k, v in previous_dict.items()]
# ['normal.: 0.9936']
```